# RDS Postgres read replica as multi-az via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I found an interesting article about using RDS read replica as multi-AZ.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/amazon-rds-read-replicas-now-support-multi-az-deployments/?nc1=h_ls

I found that I can do this using the AWS console:
[image]
So I would like to deploy this strategy using Terraform, but there is nothing about deploying a Postgresql database read replica as multi-AZ in the Terraform documentation.

Is there an example for multi-AZ read replicas?

Answer (score 0):

The [`multi_az` parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#multi_az) of the [`aws_db_instance` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html) sets where the instance should have a replica in another availability zone.

Comment: multi_az parameter is just a boolean parameter you can't say which type of az ( the classic one or with replica)

Comment: multi_az is boolean because that is how multiAZ feature works, you either enable it or don't. I have no idea what you mean by `classic` and `with replica`.

Comment: @Matus Dubrava, did you read my question ?, I want to use the read replica as multi-AZ